# Como percorrer um arraylist em busca de um elemento específico?

Tags: java, arraylist

Criei um Arraylist que me retorna uma consulta do SQL Server.
Preciso fazer buscas dentro desse array por valores específicos. Tentei utilizar o `contains`, que até funciona, porém sempre me retorna apenas o valor da primeira linha da minha coluna.

Abaixo seria mais ou menos a lógica que preciso e funciona, porém a consulta é feita apenas na primeira linha e não em tudo e por conta disso não encontra valores que existem na tabela em que fiz a consulta...
A minha dúvida é essa, eu não sei com percorrer todo o array para verificar se meu elemento existe ou não.

```
    if(valor.containsValue("TESTE")){
        Insere.setText("TESTE Encontrado!") 
    } else {
        Insere.setText("TESTE Não Encontrado!")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, acredito que esse `valor.containsValue('TESTE')` seja a coluna que você citou mas sua pergunta poderia ter mais detalhes pois não mostra como vocẽ está lendo essa coluna dentro do seu ArrayList.

Entretanto, acredito que o que você procura vai ser encontrado adicionando uma estrutura de for, que vai conter esse if/else que você fez e afirma que está funcionando para um resultado, pois assim, todo o seu arraylist será varrido e cada elemento será verificado:

```
    suaLista.forEach(valor -> {
        if(valor.containsValue("TESTE")){
            Insere.setText("TESTE Encontrado!") 
        } else {
            Insere.setText("TESTE Não Encontrado!")
        }
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado!! Consegui corrigir de outra forma...

Answer (score -3):

Poderia colocar o código que você está usando.

Mas a ideia não é muito complicado, no momento em que você colocar essa resposta vinda do banco num array ou algo parecido e na sequencia faça um laço para percorrer e dentro desse laço coloque os condicionais, os ifs.